# Problema al hacer un INSERT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Estoy teniendo problemas con un procedimiento almacenado que se trata de generar vacaciones.

Pues resulta que la parte del `UPDATE` si la realiza bien pero lo del `INSERT` no funciona ya que si hay mas periodos con nombre `PROPORCIONAL` aunque el `id` del usuario sean distintos no se crea.

Esta es la parte donde se supone que hacia la validación, en caso de que en la tabla movimientos no exista un periodo `PROPORCIONAL` del `Id_Usu` debería crearse.

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MovimientoVacaciones mov WHERE mov.ID_EMPLEADO = U.Id_Usu AND mov.ANO = 'PROPORCIONAL')

ALTER PROC [dbo].[pVerificarPeriodoProporcional]
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.MovimientoVacaciones mv INNER JOIN dbo.Empleados e ON mv.ID_EMPLEADO = e.Id_Usu WHERE ANO = 'PROPORCIONAL')
    BEGIN
        -- Llamar a pGenerarVacaciones para manejar el periodo 'PROPORCIONAL'
        DECLARE @VerificacionExitosa BIT
        EXEC [dbo].[pGenerarVacaciones] @VerificacionExitosa OUTPUT

        IF @VerificacionExitosa = 1
        BEGIN
            -- Update the existing 'PROPORCIONAL' period
            UPDATE mv
            SET mv.VACACIONES_GENERADAS = CASE 
                    WHEN Antiguedad.años < 1 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 36)
                    WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 1 AND Antiguedad.años < 2 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 30)
                    WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 2 AND Antiguedad.años < 3 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 24)
                    WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 3 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 18)
                    ELSE 0
                END,
                mv.Inicio = GETDATE(),
                mv.Fin = GETDATE(),
                mv.Antiguedad = (DATEDIFF(DAY, U.FechaIngreso, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)/365),
                mv.VACACIONES_DISFRUTADAS = CASE 
                    WHEN ((Antiguedad.años < 1) AND (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 36) = 0) THEN 0
                    WHEN ((Antiguedad.años >= 1 AND Antiguedad.años < 2) AND (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 30) = 0) THEN 0
                    WHEN ((Antiguedad.años >= 2 AND Antiguedad.años < 3) AND (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 24) = 0) THEN 0
                    WHEN (Antiguedad.años >= 3 AND (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 18) = 0) THEN 0
                    ELSE mv.VACACIONES_DISFRUTADAS
                END
            FROM dbo.MovimientoVacaciones mv
            INNER JOIN dbo.Empleados U ON mv.ID_EMPLEADO = U.Id_Usu
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[FunctionCalcularAntiguedad](GETDATE()) Antiguedad ON U.Id_Usu = Antiguedad.Id_Usu
            WHERE mv.ANO = 'PROPORCIONAL'
        END
    END
    
    ELSE
       BEGIN
        -- Create the 'PROPORCIONAL' period
        INSERT INTO dbo.MovimientoVacaciones 
        SELECT U.Id_Usu, Anio = 'PROPORCIONAL',
            Dias = CASE 
                WHEN Antiguedad.años < 1 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 36)
                WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 1 AND Antiguedad.años < 2 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 30)
                WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 2 AND Antiguedad.años < 3 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 24)
                WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 3 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 18)
                ELSE 0
            END,
            Inicio = GETDATE(),
            Fin = GETDATE(),
            0,
            Antiguedad = (DATEDIFF(DAY, U.FechaIngreso, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)/365)
        FROM dbo.Empleados U
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[FunctionCalcularAntiguedad](GETDATE()) Antiguedad ON U.Id_Usu = Antiguedad.Id_Usu
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MovimientoVacaciones mov WHERE mov.ID_EMPLEADO = U.Id_Usu AND mov.ANO = 'PROPORCIONAL')
    END

END
```

Comment: Si no explicas la regla de negocio que estás tratando de implementar, no veo cómo ver cuál es el problema en el código. Lectura recomendada: [ask].

Comment: Hola, lo que deseo hacer es que si en la tabla MovimientoVacaciones no existe un periodo llamado "PROPORCIONAL" correspondinte al usuario entonces se cree, y si existe entonces se actualize

Comment: Faltaría un where en la cláusula select del primer `if` entonces, ¿no?. Además, ¿por qué es necesario el join en ese select?

Comment: El primer if si funciona ya que si existe un registro con el Anio = 'PROPORCIONAL'  si los actualiza pero si no existe no los crea.

Comment: El error está en el select de la sentencia insert/select entonces, asegúrate que ese select SI devuelva el o los registros que quieres insertar.

Comment: Si ejecuto ese select si me devuelve los datos lo que no se por que no los inserta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147662/discussion-between-jachguate-and-emin-urbina).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para escribir esta respuesta estoy tomando en cuenta información proporcionada en [esta sala de chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147662/discussion-between-jachguate-and-emin-urbina) asociada a la pregunta.

El problema que tienes es que entre una y otra puede cambiar la información de la tabla `Empleados`, por lo que habrá algunos empleados que pueden tener el registro de `MovimientoVacaciones` y otros no, por lo que en algunos casos quieres insertar y en otros actualizar, pero actualmente el procedimiento almacenado tiene un único IF y, o actualiza o inserta.

Hay que cambiar esta lógica por una que inserte lo que haga falta y actualice lo que haga falta. No he leido a detalle el código, ni voy a hacerlo, porque no hace falta para ayudarte a resolver el problema.

Suponiendo que ambas instrucciones realizan la acutalización y la inserción masiva, es tan sencillo como quitar el IF y ejecutar ambas en secuencia.

OJO, que solo estoy quitando la sentencia, no estoy validando el resto de instrucciones, suponiendo que funcionan correctamente.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[pVerificarPeriodoProporcional]
AS
BEGIN
        -- Llamar a pGenerarVacaciones para manejar el periodo 'PROPORCIONAL'
        DECLARE @VerificacionExitosa BIT
        EXEC [dbo].[pGenerarVacaciones] @VerificacionExitosa OUTPUT

        IF @VerificacionExitosa = 1
        BEGIN
            -- Update the existing 'PROPORCIONAL' period
            UPDATE mv
            SET mv.VACACIONES_GENERADAS = CASE 
                    WHEN Antiguedad.años < 1 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 36)
                    WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 1 AND Antiguedad.años < 2 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 30)
                    WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 2 AND Antiguedad.años < 3 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 24)
                    WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 3 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 18)
                    ELSE 0
                END,
                mv.Inicio = GETDATE(),
                mv.Fin = GETDATE(),
                mv.Antiguedad = (DATEDIFF(DAY, U.FechaIngreso, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)/365),
                mv.VACACIONES_DISFRUTADAS = CASE 
                    WHEN ((Antiguedad.años < 1) AND (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 36) = 0) THEN 0
                    WHEN ((Antiguedad.años >= 1 AND Antiguedad.años < 2) AND (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 30) = 0) THEN 0
                    WHEN ((Antiguedad.años >= 2 AND Antiguedad.años < 3) AND (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 24) = 0) THEN 0
                    WHEN (Antiguedad.años >= 3 AND (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 18) = 0) THEN 0
                    ELSE mv.VACACIONES_DISFRUTADAS
                END
            FROM dbo.MovimientoVacaciones mv
            INNER JOIN dbo.Empleados U ON mv.ID_EMPLEADO = U.Id_Usu
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[FunctionCalcularAntiguedad](GETDATE()) Antiguedad ON U.Id_Usu = Antiguedad.Id_Usu
            WHERE mv.ANO = 'PROPORCIONAL'
        END
    END
    
        -- Create the 'PROPORCIONAL' period
        INSERT INTO dbo.MovimientoVacaciones 
        SELECT U.Id_Usu, Anio = 'PROPORCIONAL',
            Dias = CASE 
                WHEN Antiguedad.años < 1 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 36)
                WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 1 AND Antiguedad.años < 2 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 30)
                WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 2 AND Antiguedad.años < 3 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 24)
                WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 3 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 18)
                ELSE 0
            END,
            Inicio = GETDATE(),
            Fin = GETDATE(),
            0,
            Antiguedad = (DATEDIFF(DAY, U.FechaIngreso, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)/365)
        FROM dbo.Empleados U
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[FunctionCalcularAntiguedad](GETDATE()) Antiguedad ON U.Id_Usu = Antiguedad.Id_Usu
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MovimientoVacaciones mov WHERE mov.ID_EMPLEADO = U.Id_Usu AND mov.ANO = 'PROPORCIONAL')

END
```

Si tus rutinas actuales no soportan lo que he descrito, sería de hacer los ajustes necesarios para que lo hagan, pues no tienes de otra que insertar lo que haga falta y actualizar (todo o parcialmente).

De hecho, si el volumen de datos no es tan alto, puedes invertir el orden, para  iniciar siempre insertando los registros que haga falta, incluso con la información básica para que cumplan con las reglas de la tabla y luego correr la actualización sobre todos los registros. Es un poco más ineficiente, pero el intercambio de simplicidad por eficiencia no siempre es malo. Si no hay una alta carga transaccional y el volumen de datos lo permite, suele ser más barato pagar un procesador un poco más rápido o más memoria que pagar programadores que puedan desarrollar y dar mantenimiento a un sistema más complejo.

Comment: SOLO TENGO QUE DECIRTE GRACIAS BENDITO GENIO